# Clone a users data to a new table before deleting them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am looking for some direction on how to better handle the deletion of users. Ideally, a users data would be copied and stored into a new table before the columns get nullified in `archive!`. What is the best way to setup a model and migration to clone the users data before archiving them?

In the users_controller, the destroy method is simple

```
 def destroy
    load_user
    @user.archive!
    flash[:notice] = 'User deleted'
    redirect_to action: :index
    ...
  end
```

The archive! action in the user model nullifies all of the user columns, and adds a suffix to the end of the users email with the time the user was deleted.

```
def archive!
    self.is_archived = true

    self.email = "#{self.email}.archived#{Time.now.to_i}"
    self.encrypted_password = nil
    self.password_salt      = nil
    self.session_token      = nil
    self.perishable_token   = nil
    self.device_id          = nil
    self.verification_key   = nil
    self.save!

    self.update_column(:api_key, nil)
    UserGroup.delete_all(:user_id => self.id)
  end
```

Comment: Why not just make a new table (`ArchivedUsers`) and then there's no need to append information to existing columns - just make a new column called `deleted_at` (for example)

Comment: @dax How do I handle moving the user to (`ArchiveUsers`) before nullifying their information in the User table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to simply make a new table - `ArchivedUsers` with all the same attributes as `Users` plus whatever other information you'd like (such as `deleted_at`).

Then your `archive!` method could look like this:

```
def archive!
  additional_attributes = {
    deleted_at: Time.now.to_i
  }

  if ArchivedUser.create!(self.attributes.merge(additional_attributes))
    self.destroy!
  else
    # handle the ArchivedUser not being created properly
  end
end
```